# Business Objects & Ole

Tags: api, ole, business-intelligence, business-objects

I can create simple program to connect to BO using another application using ole automation such as:

```
var bob = createObject('BusinessObjects.Application');
bob.visible = true;
bob.interactive = true;
bob.loginas  ('Login', 'pass' ...); 
var doc = bob.documents';
var zed = doc.open('file.rep'); ... etc.
```

but is it possible to already write the SQL query in the application that connects to the BO universe and extract the data etc... (without having to invoke any already authored rep file)? The thing is I want to be able to completely manipulate BO through the external application. Alternatively if it's not possible, another option may be to connect to a BO universe and perform SQL queries there, is it possible to dispatch an SQL query to a BO universe using something like ODBC connectivity? Thanks

Comment: Guys I'm going to lose 50 points anyway, why doesn't anyone just answer whatever they want, just so that I can give them the 50 points of bounty, otherwise they are gone wasted (in 4 hrs).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SimbaEngine ODBC SDK 8.1 ?